# properly understanding inject in angular14 - inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, inject, angular14

I'm trying to learn the changes in angular 14, especially the `inject()` feature where i'm able to inject modules to functions and i don't need to create special services for that.. but i think i got something wrong.

I'm trying to create some static functions to send snack messages using the package `ngx-toastr`, but this package is not relevant to my question. how do I properly implement functions that show snack messages while injecting to them the required modules that they need to operate.

this is my `messages.ts` file:

```
import {inject} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';


export const snackMsgSuccess = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
  const toaster = inject(ToastrService);
  toaster.success(msg, title, {
    easeTime: 1000
  });
};


export const snackMsgInfo = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
  const toaster = inject(ToastrService);
  toaster.info(msg, title, {
    easeTime: 1000
  });
};

export const snackMsgWarn = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
  const toaster = inject(ToastrService);
  toaster.warning(msg, title, {
    easeTime: 1000
  });
};


export const snackMsgError = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
  const toaster = inject(ToastrService);
  toaster.error(msg, title, {
    easeTime: 1000
  });
};
```

and I got the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context (a constructor, a factory function or a field initializer)
```

well... i had a problem before when i tried to have a supporting function to get route params:

```
export const routeParam$ = (key: string) => {
  const activatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);

  return activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    pluck(key),
    filter(r => r !== null),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
};
```

and i was only able to use as an field initializer in a component with `task: Observable<string> = routeParam$('task');`

well the error message is very clear... but still.. i'm new to angular14 and i thought that inject would allow me to do that. it's not that useful for me otherwise.

for now I moved it as a service..

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MsgService {

  constructor(private toaster: ToastrService) {
  }

  public snackMsgSuccess = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
    this.toaster.success(msg, title, {
      easeTime: 1000
    });
  };


  public snackMsgInfo = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
    this.toaster.info(msg, title, {
      easeTime: 1000
    });
  };

  public snackMsgWarn = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
    this.toaster.warning(msg, title, {
      easeTime: 1000
    });
  };


  public snackMsgError = (msg: string, title?: string) => {
    this.toaster.error(msg, title, {
      easeTime: 1000
    });
  };
}
```

but is this the only way to implement it ? even in angular14 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the Answer, It can be only initialised during instantiation of a dependency by the DI system. You can workaround this by creating higher order function.

```
export const snackMsgSuccess = () => {
  const toaster = inject(ToastrService);
  return (msg: string,title?: string)=>{
    toaster.success(msg, title, {
      easeTime: 1000
    });
  }
};
```

**component.ts**

```
snackMsgSuccess = snackMsgSuccess();


ngOnInit(){
   this.snackMsgSuccess('Success','Test');
}
```

**Update Angular 14.1**

In this version inject function can be used inside function body using runInContext API.

**[For More Info](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-runincontext-api-in-angular-f8996d7e00da)**

Comment: I like this solution better than using `runInContext` because consumers don't need to inject the injector, then call the `runInContext(...)`.  Assigning a local variable does the same thing,  but allows the usage to be simpler IMO.  Prepending the function name with "inject" might be a good convention to make it obvious that execution must occur in the constructor (*or "on the class"*).  `snackMsgSuccess = injectSnackMsgSuccess()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Angular 14.1 you can use the [runInContext](https://angular.io/api/core/EnvironmentInjector#runincontext) :

Simple example:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(private injector: EnvironmentInjector) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // can't inject()

            this.injector.runInContext(() => {
                inject(MyService) // fine
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the v16+ use [runInInjectionContext](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/49396)

```
injector = inject(EnvironmentInjector);
```

or

```
constructor(private injector: EnvironmentInjector)
```

and then

```
runInInjectionContext(this.injector, snackMsgSuccess);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for one of my Angular projects using Nx and Angular 15 without breaking this rule. I got it solved adding the following line to `compilerOptions.paths` in the tsconfig.base.json file:

`"@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]`

Comment: could you explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

One reason why you may receive this error is because you are dependent on a library that depends on a different version of Angular than your main package does, and you are importing that library's module into your Angular module.

You should be able to determine this by looking at `node_modules/some_library/node_modules`, and seeing if `@angular` libraries are present there.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76643789/3532720) is a workaround for that. The proper solution is to make sure your main package and the library you depend on are using the same versions of `@angular` packages. One way to do this is to make sure you have the same major version, and use `^` as your semver prefix for `@angular` packages in your `package.json`.